# wildcard searches are working the opposite o would expect them to, am I writing the query incorrectly?

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

I have the below query.  I am looking for any table in my database that contains the phrase "ssn".  It should include "SSN".  Since I am using the LIKE operator and the % wildcard I would expect that terms such as "Employee_SSN", "Spouse SSN", "ssn" would show up in the query results.  However that is not the case.  In fact if I don't enter the SSN in all capitals it will be rejected.  I'm not sure if I accidentally changed one of the settings or something like that but this seems off to me.

```
select owner, table_name  from all_tab_columns  where column_name LIKE x
```

> '%SSN%'

Comment: Try `where upper(column_name) LIKE '%SSN%'`

Comment: What about `where regexp_like(column_name,'ssn','i')` as another option ..

Answer (score 0):

```
create table so_case_cols (
 SSN varchar2(11),
 "ssn" varchar2(11),
 "ssN" varchar2(11));

select * from user_tab_cols where upper(column_name) like '%SSN%';
```

We recommend you do not use case sensitive column names, but if you do, you need to account for that.

A common technique is to use the UPPER() or LOWER() function on in your PREDICATE clause, and then search for the uppercase or lowercase text, which will cover all possible permutations.

[image]

12c Release 2 (12.2) also makes it easier to deal with searching for text values. [Oracle-Base has a nice how-to here.](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/column-level-collation-and-case-insensitive-database-12cr2#column-level)